# String control with for-loop and dict in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop

I wrote a dict:

```
msgs = {"msg_1" : "a", "msg_2" : "b", "msg_3" : "c"}
```

now I don't want to read in the dict manually, because I don't know how many elements will be in there (I read the dict from a file):

```
z = "msg_{j}"
for i in range(1, len(msgs) - 1):
    y = z.format(j=i) # This makes it "msg_1", "msg_2", "msg_3", ...
    print(msgs[y])
```

This throws a `KeyError: msg_1`.
If I print out one-by-one it works just fine:

```
print(msgs["msg_1"])
print(msgs["msg_2"])
print(msgs["msg_3"])

... a
... b
... c
```

Any idea what the reason is?
Why is this the case?

I tested all the functions and everything work just fine, until I get to the part with the loop (and if I use print() instead of the loop it works fine).

Comment: The code you have shown seems to have resolved the issue you have in your actual code. On another note, `range(1, len(msgs)-1)` would only only iterate through 1 item - because range stops at `n-1`, So you need `range(1, len(msgs)+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to iterate over your dictionary.

For Python 2.x:

```
for key, value in msgs.iteritems():
```

For Python 3.x:

```
for key, value in msgs.items():
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, replace `len(msgs) - 1` with `len(msgs) + 1`,

```
msgs = {"msg_1" : "a", "msg_2" : "b", "msg_3" : "c"}

z = "msg_{j}"
for i in range(1, len(msgs) + 1):
    y = z.format(j=i) # This makes it "msg_1", "msg_2", "msg_3", ...
    print(msgs[y])


# Output
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your are missing the `.keys()` method of `dict` object. It returns a list of all keys in the `dict` object.

```
for key in msgs.keys():
    print msgs[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution from SarTheFirst. If you want to print in sorted order:

```
for key in sorted(msg):
    print(msgs[key])
```

Comment: This may not be sorted the way they want `msg_1`, `msg_10`, `msg_100`, `msg_11`, `msg_12`, ... if they have 100 items.

Answer (score 0):

All of you thanks, I found the fix for exactly my problem.

```
string = "msg_{j}"
```

does not work, no idea why.
BUT what works, is that you use the `r""`.
So `string = r"msg_{j}"` works, for some reason.